# convert shapefile into x,y,z (lat/lon coords) in R

Tags: r, shapefile

I have a shapefile and am having issues extracting x, y, z components. I would also like to convert x and y to Lat and Lon from UTM.

Eventually I would like to

```
plot(x, y)
map(add=T)
```

and add other points.

for ex, How you make sense of this projection:

```
library(PBSmapping)

r <- importShapefile("~/Desktop/BIO_CA_KelpPersistent/BIO_CA_KelpPersistent.shp")
 str(r)

- attr(*, "prj")= chr "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_California_Teale_Albers\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1"| __truncated__
```

Update:

```
require(sf)
nc <- st_read("BIO_CA_KelpPersistent.shp")

nc_points <- st_coordinates(st_geometry(st_centroid(nc)))

xy <- project(nc_points, paste("+proj=aea +lat_1=34 +lat_2=40.5 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-120 +x_0=0 +y_0=-4000000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs", sep = ""), inverse=T)

plot(xy, ylim=c(32, 33), xlim=c(-119, -117))
map(add=T, lwd=2)
```

But many points are missing... how do I index this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend using `library(sf)` to read shapefiles : `sf <- sf::st_read("~/Desktop/BIO_CA_KelpPersistent/BIO_CA_KelpPersistent.shp)`

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't help me plot that data.

Comment: I think you need to provide a minimal data set within your question (i.e., not an 800mb download), then it will be much easier to see your issues and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Take a look in the rgdal/rgeos packages, it's great for working with geospatial data. Read the shapefile using readOGR(); calculate centroids using gCentroid(x, byid = TRUE); transform the coordinate system with spTransform().

Answer (score 2):

I'm using an example dataset that comes with the `sf` package. Using `sf` we don't need to convert the geometry type to x and y columns. If all you need to do is plot layers you could do something like:

```
library(sf)

# Load shapefile
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

# Plot it without converting geometry to x, y columns
plot(st_geometry(nc))
plot(st_geometry(st_centroid(nc)), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

However, if you must convert to x and y columns, you could use `st_coordinates`:

```
# Convert geometry to x, y columns
nc_points <- st_coordinates(st_geometry(st_centroid(nc)))
```

Where data that looks like this:

> ```
>                     geometry
> 1  POINT (-81.49826 36.4314)
> 2 POINT (-81.12515 36.49101)
> 3 POINT (-80.68575 36.41252)
> 4  POINT (-76.0275 36.40728)
> 5 POINT (-77.41056 36.42228)
> 6 POINT (-76.99478 36.36145)
> ```

Turns into:

> ```
>           X        Y
> 1 -81.49826 36.43140
> 2 -81.12515 36.49101
> 3 -80.68575 36.41252
> 4 -76.02750 36.40728
> 5 -77.41056 36.42228
> 6 -76.99478 36.36145
> ```

We could then plot it in a similar way:

```
# Plot
plot(st_geometry(nc))
points(nc_points)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but the entire dataset is not within this data frame.     require(sf)
nc <- st_read("BIO_CA_KelpPersistent.shp")
nc_points <- st_coordinates(st_geometry(st_centroid(nc)))
xy <- project(nc_points, paste("+proj=aea +lat_1=34 +lat_2=40.5 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-120 +x_0=0 +y_0=-4000000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs", sep = ""), inverse=T)
plot(xy)

Comment: Right, I used your same object names, see code above.

Comment: What happens when you run the code you provided in your comment? Error messages?